# Traversing a list contaner excluding the last element

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I need to traverse a `std::list` until `end() - 1` (so I don't want to include the last element when I traverse). What is an efficient way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> l{1,2,3,4,5};

    for(auto itr = l.begin(); itr != l.end() - 1; ++itr)
    {   
        cout << *itr << '\n';
    }   
}
```

Comment: So you mean the way you do it now is still not efficient "enough"?

Comment: No it is throwing error currently, and I need the efficient way also.

Comment: List's iterator does not support random access, so you can't do `l.end() - 1`. To get what is represented by `l.end() - 1`, here is a redundant way to do it: `auto end_iterator = l.end(); advance(end_iterator,-1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::list::iterator` is a [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). You can use [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) to get the iterator that you need to stop at.

```
for(auto itr = l.begin(), end = std::prev(l.end()); itr != end; ++itr)
{
   ...
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/26lJSC.

Comment: I think it's better to move the variable `end` to for loop to scope it., Like `for(auto itr = l.begin(), end = prev(l.end()); itr != end; ++itr)`

Answer (score 1):

Regardless iterator is bidirectional or not the code would be like below:

```
for (auto itr2 = l.begin(), itr = l.end(); itr2 != l.end(); itr = itr2, ++itr2) {
    if (itr != l.end()) {
        cout << *itr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: If the stl list element count is 5, then loop also will execute 5 times. This approach is also good.

Comment: It is not correct completely with list element count. One additional execution replaces `std::prev` and does nothing with list elements.

Comment: Yes correct, I meant to say the loop iteration count, but it is a different approach, i never thought of.

Comment: Did you mean to write `itr != l.end()`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thank you. I have updated my code. I copied it from my article where the name `route` is used.

Comment: @S.M. I figured as much ) I like this idea.

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
for (auto e : l | ranges::view::take(l.size() - 1))
{
    std::cout << e << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4de136c2b6e80af3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and how to use this range-v3 library?

Comment: You have to install it as any library, fix your include path and library path.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for code that works also for uni-directional iterators, I would use an advance iterator, though there is initialisation complexity for if the list is empty :

```
for (it = l.begin(), ite = l.end(), itA = (it==ite)?it:std::next(it); itA != ite; it = itA, ++itA)
{
    std::cout << e << '\n';
}
```

We are doing an extra copy per iteration, which the compiler may be able to optimise somewhat. It can't do much about the compare.

You can put the increment in the comparison for brevity, and when you *KNOW* the list is not empty, but I find that **very unreadable**:

```
if (!l.empty())
  for (it = l.begin(), ite = l.end(), itA = it; ++itA != ite; it = itA)
  {
    std::cout << e << '\n';
  }
```